# Capture MotionEvent in background

Tags: android, touch, motionevent

is that possible to get access to all touches by MotionEvent when our app is running in background? I need to get some of its properties but also at time when user uses other apps. Is this somehow possible?

Or maybe is there any other source of information how long particular touch last (when app is in background)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is yes - there is an answer with a code to get it working: [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)